# extract used column names/features from decision tree

Tags: r, random-forest, r-caret

Could someone please be so kind and point out a way of extracting the columns/features used in the fitted tree, using code like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(caret)
library(rpart)

df <- data.frame(
    x1 = rnorm(100, 3, 1)
    , x2 = rnorm(100, 5, 2)
    , y = rnorm(100, 3, 1)
)

ivs <- df %>%
    dplyr::select(
        x1
        , x2
    )

fitted <- caret::train(
     x = ivs
     , y = df$y        
)

model <-fitted$finalModel
model
```

This:

```
model$terms
```

gives you all the terms (in x) - so not necessarily the once used.

PS:

Something along those lines may be the way forward:

```
model$frame %>%
    select(
        var
    ) %>%
    filter(
        var != "<leaf>"
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The randomforest model is an ensembl of decision trees, you can use the function `varUsed` to get the variable used by tree. If you are using caret, you need to set `keep.forest=TRUE` :

```
library(caret)
set.seed(111)

X = matrix(runif(2000),ncol=20)
colnames(X) = paste0("col",1:20)
y = rnorm(100)

fitted <- train(x = X,y = y,trControl = trainControl(method="cv"),
keep.forest=TRUE,tuneGrid = data.frame(mtry=3:5))
```

And we look at the variables used, the table below tells you for each variable(row), how many times it's used in each tree(column):

```
model <-fitted$finalModel
varUsed(model,by.tree=TRUE)

dim(varUsed(model,by.tree=TRUE))
[1]  20 500

head(varUsed(model,by.tree=TRUE))
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
[1,]    1    3    1    4    1    2    2    2    2     2     1     0     3     2
[2,]    2    4    2    2    3    3    1    4    1     3     1     4     0     4
[3,]    3    1    5    1    1    0    2    2    0     1     2     1     2     1
[4,]    4    0    2    3    1    0    2    1    4     2     1     2     1     1
[5,]    0    0    1    0    1    4    3    2    2     2     3     4     0     0
[6,]    1    2    1    3    2    2    2    1    1     1     1     1     2     3
```

You can check this in detail using:

```
head(getTree(model,1,labelVar=TRUE))
  left daughter right daughter split var split point status  prediction
1             2              3     col13   0.9651637     -3  0.04972823
2             4              5     col13   0.5825061     -3 -0.05466984
3             0              0      <NA>   0.0000000     -1  2.55528193
4             6              7      col6   0.8524606     -3 -0.30132135
5             8              9     col16   0.8011010     -3  0.51518018
6            10             11      col3   0.3629737     -3 -0.45289996
```

If we tabulate the `split var` column we get the same result as the previous table.